# Using yum to upgrade from MySQL 5.1.73 to 5.7.13

Tags: yum, mysql

I've picked up an IT role and I'm new to yum so please forgive me.

*yum list* shows these mysql packages installed:

```
mysql.x86_64                            5.1.73-5.el6_6               @base      
mysql-libs.x86_64                       5.1.73-5.el6_6               @base      
mysql-server.x86_64                     5.1.73-5.el6_6               @base
```

I've been asked to upgrade the packages to 5.7.13.

The MySQL documentation refers to release series:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html#yum-repo-select-series

This command is supposed to show me "all the subrepositories in the MySQL Yum repository, and see which of them are enabled or disabled"

```
shell> yum repolist all | grep mysql
```

The command produces no output.

Assuming I'm not worried about upgrading one series at a time and am happy to jump directly from 5.1 to 5.7, how do I do that?

In that same bit of MySQL documentation I see this:

```
shell> sudo yum-config-manager --disable mysql57-community
shell> sudo yum-config-manager --enable mysql56-community
```

Should I try to disable mysql51-community, if that's what I have, and enable mysql57-community, then do *yum install mysql*?

And, related to this question, what's the backout process if I can't get 5.7.13 to work? I am working with a sandbox VM and I do have a snapshot of it so I'm not worried about trashing it if worst comes to worst.